# How to create text design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create this desgin :

[image]

Those are dynamics small block of texte from the server.

Any guide line ?

Thanks

Nico

Comment: Guidelines:Study html and css.. attempt to create this intricate design and if all is not well...then post what you have tried..

Comment: This is not the place to ask this type of question but i'll still answer. That is https://freqdec.github.io/slabText/ plugin

Comment: Check this link:-http://www.creativebloq.com/web-design-tips/css-and-javascript-1233101

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Grid system to do this. Hope you know how to load text from the server.
Use

http://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

to learn about grid system. please refer it and make sure to code to all medium devices, small devices and extra small devices as well because otherwise, it will not display properly in small devices as you expect.
Further use Text and Font CSS styles to achieve the relevant styles. 
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_text.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp

https://responsivedesign.is/resources/typography/slab-text

Hope this helps.